# How to delete a record in your database using php and staying in the same page after deleting?

Tags: php, html, database

I have a database of contributors and I want to delete some of them from my database using php. I wrote the code but it gives errors. I think I linked php and html in a wrong way. once I delete I want to stay in the same page. **Also I would like to know if I can make my code more secure. However, this page is accessed by one user who has a username and password and should enter an OTP.**
Here is the code :

```
<?php
/* Delete button */
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $query =  "DELETE FROM contributors WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";  
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}


function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "volunteedbzlfqf");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['fname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['lname'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['phone'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['DOB'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['city'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['degree'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['major'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['service'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['hours'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['hrPrice'];?></td>
                    <td><button name="modify" id="<?php.$row['id'].?>">#</button></td>
                    <td><button name="delete" id="<?php.$row['id'].?>">X</button></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
</html>
```

Comment: To do anything without reloading the page, use AJAX.

Comment: I am not sure how I can use ajax with wordpress. I am fine with reloading the page I just want to stay in it, not to move to another one.

Comment: You can stay in the same page by having the server script redirect back to the same URL.

Comment: Sounds good. But I am still having issues in my code that I am not able to correct

Answer (score 0):

When go inside delete:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    $query =  "DELETE FROM contributors WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";  
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
```

U can check if user is logged or not (the mistake is i know the URL and put like url/table/randomIdToDelete in postman and can delete your database.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']){
        return;
    }
    $query =  "DELETE FROM contributors WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."' ";  
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
```

You can use ajax for this in wordpress. See [this example link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/)

Comment: <td><button name="modify" id="<?php.$row['id'].?>">#</button></td>
                    <td><button name="delete" id="<?php.$row['id'].?>">X</button></td>

Comment: U should do this:
<td><button name="modify" id="<?php echo $row['id'].?>" onclick="myEditFunction(this.id)">#</button></td> <td><button name="delete" id="<?=.$row['id'].?> onclick="myDeleteFunction(this.id)"">X</button></td>

see that i use <?php echo and <?= (it´s the same, just depend if your server admit short tags)

And use a simple Ajax call (post or get) to edit/remove without reload the page